# Django env setting evaluates before it can check if an env variable is set

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use `values.SecretValue()` to setup my aws bucket name. To set Django's media url in the past I've used:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = values.SecretValue()
MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/{}/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

Now, even though AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME correctly pulls the value from the set enironmental varaible, MEDIA_URL is `https://s3.amazonaws.com/None/`.

This can be reproduced with these settings:

```
class Production(Common):

  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = values.SecretValue()
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = values.SecretValue()
  AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = values.SecretValue()
  MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/{}/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

  print MEDIA_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
  # -> https://s3.amazonaws.com/None/ None
```

And by running a sever with this manage.py:

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Production")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", "my-bucket")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", "my-secret")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "my-key")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "my-secret-key")

    print settings.MEDIA_URL, settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, os.environ.get('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    # -> https://s3.amazonaws.com/None/ my-bucket my-bucket

    from configurations.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

An interim fix is to use an property to evaluate the variable each time its called:

```
@property
def MEDIA_URL(self):
    return 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/{}/'.format(Production.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

But it makes more sense to set this value once at initialization.

Using Django-configurations `1.0`, and Django `1.9.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something with laziness:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

def get_media_url():
    from django.conf import settings
    return 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/{}/'.format(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

MEDIA_URL = lazy(get_media_url)()
```

Comment: Did you mean [`allow_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.allow_lazy)?

Comment: No, lazy. allow_lazy is a decorator, isn't it? I'm no laziness expert, but I think it should work.

Comment: I think lazy() is not documented in django docs, but you can find the source code here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/utils/functional/